# Architecture/Block diagram of basic Emulator

Tags: emulation

I want to understand working of basic Emulator.

Could you please provide me some basics (general architecture / block diagram) of general emulator.

OR any links for the same.
If you can suggest some white paper published for the same then it will be helpful.

Thanks

PJ

Comment: Basics of Emulator (to emulate OS). Not specific to any type. Wants to know basic architecture (block diagram) of general emulator.

Comment: What are you trying to emulate?

Comment: I am preparing one presentation on Basics of Emulator. In this, I have to include basic block or architecture of basic components involved in general OS emulator.

Answer (score 0):

[Virtual Machines: Versatile Platforms for Systems and Processes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609105) might work as a starting point.